# I keep on getting express js installation error it get installed and then when i check its version it say nothing installed like it is not recognised

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, installation

I have tried every solution present on the stack but still, the same error keeps on happening please let me know if there's any way to solve this installation error...[here I have shown you the image of my error but it keeps on saying like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDjZr.png)

```bash
express: The term 'express' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.

At line:1 char:1
+ express
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (express:String) [], Comma
   ndNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException][1]
```

Comment: The installation went fine, but `express` is not a command line utility, so you can't run it from the command line. What would you even expect to happen from just running `express`?

Comment: i want to use it to do some stuff i actually added in manually also in environment variable but still not getting any output same issue continues

Comment: Whatever that means ... But yes, the issue will continue because *there is NO CLI COMMAND in the `express` package* ...

Comment: so if have knowledge of how to use express in node js please help me then

Comment: How about reading the docs https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Comment: Cannot GET /myapp/index.js now it is giving this error no matter what i type in response i'm getting this